# React + TypeScript Accordion transition not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm creating a simple accordion with header and body. I'd like to do a animation when click on accordion button. Here is my code

`
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

```
import { type AccordionContentType } from './Accordion.types';

export const AccordionHeader = styled.button<AccordionContentType>`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2.4rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.alabaster};
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? 0 : '13px')};
  border-bottom-right-radius: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? 0 : '13px')};
  place-content: space-between;
`;

export const TitleWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const AccordionContent = styled.div<AccordionContentType>`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.alabaster};
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;

  ${({ isOpen }) =>
    isOpen &&
    css`
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      max-height: fit-content;
    `};
`;
```

`

I think it should work. The body starts with height: 0 and go to height: fit-content with transition 0.5 ease-in-out, but i dont know why this code doenst work

I'm creating a simple accordion with header and body. I'd like to do a animation when click on accordion button.